# A file on my desktop has suddenly been saying it is read only, not allowing me to change write to it with Sublime Text (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu

I have been following Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial and I have had no trouble modifying the files from within Sublime Text 2 and suddenly when I go to add a "example_user.rb" file with some code in it, it doesn't let me write to it and gives me this error. I have tried multiple things from various searches that I have made and I believe that I should do a chown command, but I can't remember it and can't seem to find it. I have tried a few different ones, but they don't seem to work.

I know this is probably a question that has been asked many times before, but I just can't seem to find the right article because I am quite new to Ubuntu and Linux in general and have no idea who to look for exactly.

```
Unable to save ~/Desktop/Rails/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
Error: /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb is readonly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo chmod -R 775 /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/sample_app` or `sudo chown -R username /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/sample_app`